# When was new hardware added Centos 7

Tags: centos7, dell

On Centos 7, is there a way to find out when was a new hardware added? My vendor says they added a new nic card on our Dell servers but now I am not sure which ones were done. Hope there is some log that shows time and date when a new nic was added. Sorry our inventory hasn't been updated for some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Time Frame**

Hardware is added with the power off, so you would be looking for times when the server was rebooted or halted to narrow down which logs to check.  The `last` command can tell you when the server was taken offline.

**Log Files**

If your system is rotating / preserving either `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/boot.log`, then you could look for which file has the first occurrence of your new devices.  It will not give you the exact time an engineer physically installed the hardware (as in, down to the minute), but it will tell you the window of time it was added.

If you have centralized syslog, then perhaps you could also search for the first time the new devices were initialized.

**[ Edit ]**

I should add that if your Dell servers have an iDrac, then the iDrac logs will also tell you when the server was powered off, in the event that `last` has rotated out.